# SurfaceView Custom Class xml?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, animation, android-studio

I'm pretty new to Android, however I recently decided to familiarize myself with animations. I quickly found out that I would need to implement a SurfaceView class.

Right now, I have gotten to a point where my ContentView is set to the custom surfaceView view (v). I want to get the surfaceView into a custom layout in the main xml file (activity_surface_view_example.xml) .

heres my Surface class code:

```
        package rdc.com.surfacegame;

/**
 * Created by Spenser on 15-04-09.
 */

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class Surface extends SurfaceView implements Runnable{
main m;
    Thread t;
    SurfaceHolder holder;
    boolean okQuestion = false;
    int a, b;    int x;



    public Surface(Context context, main m) {
        super(context);
        holder = getHolder();
        this.m=m;

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {


        while(okQuestion == true) {
            if (!holder.getSurface().isValid()) {
                continue;
            }

            Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas();
            c.drawColor(Color.GREEN);
            c.drawBitmap(m.ball, m.x, m.y, null);
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            m.x+=m.xSpeed;
            m.y+=10;


            if (m.x > 950){m.goBack = true;m.y+=100;}
            if (m.x==0){m.goBack = false; m.y+=100;}

            if(m.goBack ==true){m.x -= m.xSpeed*2;}
            if(m.y==1700){m.y=0;}

        }
    }

    public void pause(){
        okQuestion = false;
        while(true){
            try{t.join();}catch(InterruptedException e){e.printStackTrace();}
            break;
        }
        t = null;
    }


    public void resume(){
        okQuestion = true;
        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }



}
```

My main class code:

```
    package rdc.com.surfacegame;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;

public class main extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener {

    public Surface surfer;
    public Bitmap ball;
    public float x, y;
    public int xSpeed = 45;
    public boolean goBack;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //surfer = (Surface)findViewById(R.id.preview_view);

        surfer = new Surface(this, this);
        ball = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.blueball);
        x = y = 0;
        setContentView(surfer);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        surfer.pause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        surfer.resume();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

and the XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".main">


<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="200dp">


    <rdc.com.surfacegame.main.Surface
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/preview_view" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

LogCat details:

```
04-08 23:23:36.294    3587-3587/rdc.com.surfacegame I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
04-08 23:23:36.338    3587-3587/rdc.com.surfacegame D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
04-08 23:23:36.339    3587-3587/rdc.com.surfacegame E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: rdc.com.surfacegame, PID: 3587
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{rdc.com.surfacegame/rdc.com.surfacegame.main}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class rdc.com.surfacegame.main.Surface
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class rdc.com.surfacegame.main.Surface
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:757)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:377)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144)
            at rdc.com.surfacegame.main.onCreate(main.java:30)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "rdc.com.surfacegame.main.Surface" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/rdc.com.surfacegame-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:571)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:377)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144)
            at rdc.com.surfacegame.main.onCreate(main.java:30)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: rdc.com.surfacegame.main.Surface
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
            ... 24 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a LinearLayout in your XML you can just add the following:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          >

<rdc.com.surfaceview.Surface android:id="@+id/preview_view"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

To set a green background you need to comment out the
d.drawColor(Color.GREEN) in our run() method and add
a Paint variable and override onDraw method of Surface class.

In your Surface class constructor:

```
public Surface(Context context, main m)   
{
  super(context);
  this.m=m;
  Initialise();
}
public Surface(Context context)
{
  super(context);
  Initialise();
}
public Surface(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
  super(context, attrs);
  Initialise();
}
public void Initialise()
{
  holder = getHolder();
  greenPaint = new Paint();
  greenPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
  greenPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
  greenPaint.setStrokeWidth(6.0f);
  greenPaint.setColor(Color.argb(255, 0, 198, 0));
}
public void SetActivity(main m)
{
  this.m = m;
}
```

Override onDraw method in Surface class

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
  super.onDraw(canvas);
  int width = this.getWidth();
  int height = this.getHeight();
  int radius = width > height ? height/2 : width/2;
  int center_x = width/2;
  int center_y = height/2;

  canvas.drawRect(center_x - radius, center_y - radius, center_x + radius, center_y + radius, greenPaint);
}
```

Surface run() method

```
@Override
public void run()
{
  while (okQuestion == true)
  {
    if  (!holder.getSurface().isValid())
    {
      continue;
    }

  Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas();
  c.drawColor(Color.GREEN);
  c.drawBitmap(m.ball, m.x, m.y, null);
  holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
  m.x+=m.xSpeed;
  m.y+=10;


  if (m.x > 950)
  {
    m.goBack = true;m.y+=100;
  }

  if (m.x==0)
  {
    m.goBack = false; m.y+=100;
  }

  if(m.goBack ==true)
  {
    m.x -= m.xSpeed*2;
    int width = this.getWidth();
    int height = this.getHeight();
    int radius = width > height ? height/2 : width/2;
    int center_x = width/2;
    int center_y = height/2;
    c.drawRect(center_x - radius, center_y - radius, center_x + radius, center_y + radius, greenPaint);
  }
  if(m.y==1700){m.y=0;}

}
```

}

main's onCreate function

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstace)
{
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  surfer = (Surface)findViewById(R.id.preview_view);
  surfer.SetActivity(this);
}
```